# Flex DataGrid, Row Group Headers

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, custom-component

I am trying to extend the DataGrid to allow headers for different groups of rows. However, I cannot figure out which method to extend from DataGrid that would allow me to accomplish this.

I do not want the headers to be included in the dataProvider, only the rows. I want to specify indexes to insert the headers at using a property of the custom datagrid.

Here is a quick photoshop showing what I am trying to do:
[Example http://www.maclema.com/groupheaders.png](http://www.maclema.com/groupheaders.png)

Is there any custom component already built that will do this?

If not, does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: No, I just ended up using a combination of VBox's, with DataGrids and got close to what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this component:
http://code.google.com/p/flex-spreadsheet/

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that I just found to this type of problem is the following

here is the demo:
http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/SplitColumns/dg.swf

here is the discussion:
http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/thinking_about_item_renderers_1.html